# Error on Build: library/nginx no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

See a change on build definition's Agent pool from Hosted Linux Preview to Hosted VS2017 and our build started failing with the below error. Please let me know if anyone know a solution to this?

FROM nginx

latest: Pulling from library/nginx

no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries

[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosted VS2017 gives you a VM running on Windows Server 2016 and if you inspect the manifest for 'nginx' docker image as shown below -

```
docker manifest inspect nginx
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
   "manifests": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 948,
         "digest": "sha256:5b49c8e2c890fbb0a35f6050ed3c5109c5bb47b9e774264f4f3aa85bb69e2033",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 948,
         "digest": "sha256:eb5069e1c31931141bc0bf662c3cc9bf066301fc6e32c5496698e3ded105bf57",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "arm",
            "os": "linux",
            "variant": "v7"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 948,
         "digest": "sha256:c8edfc15df5e0f4d7277a4760d94efd6a1d6b791c88f4dac484ca41ac35488ec",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "arm64",
            "os": "linux",
            "variant": "v8"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 948,
         "digest": "sha256:f29ce102a2241ded2bcf9c0859993cb07b274b9991ac8f82ea11f90a3a091d43",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "386",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 948,
         "digest": "sha256:342ddde788738b726daf52577c2a67ad255ea907c10514b4989a68775d2be7c3",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "ppc64le",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 948,
         "digest": "sha256:23e1d058ec0a775cb7c803a3acdabcce3c05fd4e0f199e8ffd18e8ff2a6a019a",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "s390x",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

the supported OS is only linux (on respective architecture).

So either you would have to develop a custom nginx image using a windows based parent image and use that in your Dockerfile for above build.

Here is a sample [nginx](https://github.com/sixeyed/dockerfiles-windows/tree/master/nginx) image build on top of microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016

Comment: I am trying to change the Agent pool from Hosted VS2017 to Hosted Ubuntu 16.0.4 to see if that works. The build used to be successful when we were using Hosted Linux Preview. But now Hosted Linux Preview has been deprecated. Do you think using Hosted Ubuntu 16.0.4 will help? And while using this new Agent Pool do I need to make any changes to my Build pipeline environment or to the Docker File?

Comment: If you change to Hosted Ubuntu you shouldn't require any pipeline | Dockerfile change.

Comment: Thanks Sujay, I see that your last comment today. You are correct. It worked without any issues when I changed to Hosted Ubuntu.